# Nightwatch.js - Element present but not visible

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I have an element I'd like to check the content of, however, nightwatch isn't recoginsing it, even though it is visible on the screen.

```
  browser.waitForElementPresent('mySelector', 20000) //this succeeds
  browser.waitForElementVisible('mySelector', 20000) //this fails
  browser.verify.containsText('mySelector', 'text') //this also fails (of course)
```

I checked screenshots at fails, and **I can definitely see the html element** containing the text I'm looking at, and it works with other similar elements I have.

I'm curious to know what nightwatch itself is looking at when checking for visibility, because I cannot see any hidden attributes in the html element either.

Comment: Can you share the HTML dom, maybe the element is covered by some hidden elements that you cannot see with your eyes?

Comment: Like mention above.
Please share the HTML dom, it might me covered by an Iframe or it need to me highlighted, mouse hover over etc

Comment: How was this solved? Having the same problem where the selectors are correct, i can see the element, but nightwatch is failing.

Answer (score -1):

Problem was with the fact that elements with the same selector stayed in the DOM. Solved by using nth child.